# How to avoid generating empty text nodes in Marionette?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I used Marionette in my application, but I found it generated many empty text nodes and blank tag. Like this:

[image]

How to avoid it?

Comment: Looks like your template engine rendered empty value e.g null or undefined.  If it is an array, use _.compact () to remove null elements first.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use the tagName property on a view to generate an html element of that type.   Setting tagName to "li" or "table" or whatever would generate an outer tag in your html instead of a "div".

From the look of the resulting html, though, it seems that there may be some error in your template.  Marionette should not generate the extra "div" and certainly not a blank " ".

Comment: Do you think it may be generated by the jQueryUI? You can see I use jQuery dialog. I developed it in TypeScript and Dust.

Comment: Have a quick look at my blog on using TypeScript and Marionette. This blog uses Marionette template engine, not dust - so it may be dust related. http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/typescript-using-backbone-marionette-and-rest-webapi-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

After debugging all related sources, I found this issue was caused by dustjs(filename is backbone.marionette.dust.js).

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function (template, data) {
  var html;
  // Template must be compiled and in the dust cache. Recommend pre-compiling
  // and loading the templates as scripts at app start.
  dust.render(template, data, function (err, out) {
    html = out;
  });
  html = html.trim();//This line was added by me.
  return html;
};
```

The empty text nodes don't appear any more after this line 'html = html.trim();' was added.